# why does dataframe.resample('B') move data points back in time?

Tags: python, pandas

This is unexpected to me:

```
In[18]: TimeSeries([1.0], index=[datetime(2012, 1, 1)]).resample('B')
Out[17]: 
2011-12-30    1
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

Why is that data point moved back to the 30th rather than just ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resample` is grouping times according to the frequency, and then aggregating the associated values according to the `how` method, which is by default taking the mean.

```
In [42]: x = pd.TimeSeries([1.0], index=[DT.datetime(2012, 1, 1)])

In [43]: x.resample('B')
Out[43]: 
2011-12-30    1
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

In contrast, `asfreq` simply reindexes the TimeSeries to the desired frequency, with no aggregation:

```
In [44]: x.asfreq('B')
Out[44]: Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it would back to 2011? 'B' = business days right? In 2012, the first week of the year starts on 1/2/12. The first monday is on 1/2/12 as well. 12/31 is on a Sat.

Comment: @DataSwede: The `B` frequency groups Friday to Sunday as one group. Since 2012-1-1 is a Sunday, it get grouped with Friday, 2011-12-30.